# Data Explorer contains Stack Overflow questions with NULL ViewCount

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

While trying to examine the [distribution of question view counts](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/revision/94184/112568/question-view-count-distribution) on Stack Exchange sites, I came across an anomaly - there appear to be questions in the database with `NULL` `ViewCount`s. This query I ran on Stack Overflow found a small (but not insignificant) number of questions with this. They all appear to be questions asked between 12.41pm and 12.55pm on 13 January.

```
SELECT Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount, CreationDate FROM Posts 
WHERE PostTypeId = 1 AND ViewCount IS NULL
ORDER BY CreationDate
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/94219/112591/questions-with-null-viewcount

#### Edit:

These are the [last few questions to be imported into the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/94231/112597/). I'm guessing they got a `ViewCount` of `NULL` because their `ViewCount` is actually zero.

Comment: Which has always confused me. Doesn't the initial viewing of the post on submit = 1?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to have been fixed at some point.

Comment: This problem is showing up again...: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/996204/1232643